# angularjs Select options with counditions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made and angularJS select menu which is working fine:

```
<select 
    name="s1" 
    id="s1" 
    multiple="multiple" 
    data-native-menu="false" 
    data-role="none"
    ng-model="userlistSelect" 
    ng-options="u.userId as u.firstName for u in member.getList()">
</select>
```

And my controller is:

```
$scope.member = items;
```

How can I achieve the following:  if `firstName` is not available, then show `emailID`?

Comment: Put that logic in your controller

Comment: I posted controller code line there . How to so it there ?

Comment: why have you used .getList() method? Your controller doesn't have one !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change ng-options to display the emailID when firstName is falsy...

```
ng-options="u.userId as (u.firstName || u.emailID) for u in member.getList()"
```

[Live Demo - Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzcZf/)